# E: Unable to locate package libsane-extras

Tags: 20.04, scanner

I am trying to install the `sane` package in ubuntu 20.04 to be able to use a scanner but for some reason I cannot install the libsane-extras package.

```
admin:~$ sudo apt-get install sane sane-utils libsane-extras xsane
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsane-extras
```

What can I do to install?

Fun fact: A few months ago, simple scanner recognized my HP scanner model

Answer (score 0):

Just install without that 'libsane-extras' package. Unless you have a model that isn't part of official SANE.

" This package includes some backends that are not yet included into the official SANE distribution. Currently, they are :

- geniusvp2 (Genius ColorPage-Vivid Pro II)
- ls5000 (Nikon LS-5000 ED, Coolscan 5000 ED)"

If you have one of the 'not officially support' models then find/download the package
https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libsane-extras

and install with

> sudo dpkg -i <downloaded_package_deb_file>

Let us know if this helped.